# How to add multi-select field in magento2 ui form

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, uicomponent, multiselect-attribute

I have created a custom module in magento2. And created ui component form to save title and sort_order value, now I want to add brands as multi-select field in my module's form.

How to add a multi-select field for brands attribute options?

Comment: Hello, Your code created a multiselect field. I'm trying to get all brands options in multiselect options.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Add new field in UI form**

```
<field name="group">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="options" xsi:type="object">{Vendor}\{Module}\Model\Model\Source\Myvalues</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Your Label</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">multiselect</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
```

**Now create `Myvalues.php` to provide multiselect options at**

> app/code/{Vendor}/{Module}/Model/Source/Myvalues.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Source\Myvalues;

class Myvalues implements \Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface
{
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        return [
            ['value' => 1, 'label' => __('Test One')],
            ['value' => 2, 'label' => __('Test Two')],
            ['value' => 3, 'label' => __('Test Three')],
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your post, I have updated `Myvalues.php` to get brands options.

Comment: @VinayaMaheshwari SImple assign brand collection to option. Assign `app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/ResourceModel/Brand/Collection` to 
 _<item name="options" xsi:type="object">_ OR you can get brand collection in MyValue.php and return collection array to `toOptionArray()`.

Comment: Yes I updated code.

Comment: I want to ask what inside \Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface ?

Comment: @fudu `ArrayInterface` is interface which extends `OptionSourceInterface`  with `toOptionArray()` method

Comment: Hi, may i ask why its not run into toOptionArray() function? I implements \Magento\Framework\Data\OptionSourceInterface just like what the file said.
Please help. Check edit 2 for more information. Thanks you
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/238037/magento-2-2-5-explain-about-how-the-multi-select-available-sort-by-get-data

Comment: and how get selected values in controller ?

Comment: @HaFizUmer You can get selected group value by `$this->getRequest()->getParam('group');` or get all parameters `$this->getRequest()->getParams();`

Comment: i have one issue i need to hold Ctrl key to select more then one option is there any solution that i dont have to hold Ctrl key while multi select

Comment: @AsadUllah It's a default browser behavior. You can add custom js for multi select field.